# Python - Best Module to write into XLS files

Tags: python

I want to **read a text file**, write into an windows .xls file ie., **create a .xls file** and later do some **modifications to the created .xls file**. I have google'd as to what are all the available packages:

```
Win32 Com client
 --> xlrd (Only for Reading from xls files I guess)
|
 --> xlwt (only for writing into xls files)
PyExcelerator
```

What is the best module to perform these actions? Any suggestions?

Comment: So, what's wrong with xlwt, I've never had trouble with it.

Comment: No Josh, I am not saying that there is something wrong with xlwt. I am just asking for opinions as to which is the best module to go with.

Comment: I see, thought there was gap in needs between xlwt and xlrd that I didn't realize.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/) works great.

If you want to create `.xlsx` files (the new format used in Office 2007 and 2010), there is [openpyxl](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/).

I would recommend a native python library (xlwt or openpyxl) over using PyWin32 COM automation to drive Excel.

Comment: Here's an update: for creating `.xlsx` files there is also [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module, worth looking.