# Which module has more option to read and write xlsx extension files using Python?

Tags: python

I have to read and write data's into .xlsx extentsion files using python. And I have to use cell formatting features like merging cells,bold,font size,color etc..So which python module is good to use ?

Answer (score 1):

`xlrd` and `xlwt` may help you. Have a look into http://www.python-excel.org/.

Comment: xlrd and xlwt won't support .xlsx extension files.It will support only .xls extension only.

Comment: Oh ok. I used it once in my project to write excel file, haven't tried with new format. There are couple of similar questions in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825300/python-best-module-to-write-into-xls-files, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257771/python-writing-to-excel-2007-files-xlsx-files. you can try it out.

Answer (score 1):

openpyxl is the only library I know of that can read and write xlsx files. It's down side is that when you edit an existing file it doesn't save the original formatting or charts. A problem I'm dealing with right now. If anyone knows a work around please let me know.